# How to connect to the enterprise network in Android 12?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on an enterprise application where we need to connect with the device WiFi through X509 certificate authentication. The code that we have right now was working until Android 11. On Android 12 we are not able to establish any WiFi connection.

Below is the code snippet that we are using right now

```
while (aliases.HasMoreElements)
 {
    string alias = (string)aliases.NextElement();
    certClient = (X509Certificate)keyStore.GetCertificate(alias);
    IKey temp = keyStore.GetKey(alias, clientCertPassword.ToCharArray());
    Java.Lang.Object spec = keyFactory.GetKeySpec(temp, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec)));
    IPrivateKey pKey = keyFactory.GeneratePrivate((IKeySpec)spec);
    entConfig.SetClientKeyEntry(pKey, certClient); //Getting exception on this line on Android 12.
 }
```

`entConfig.SetClientKeyEntry(pKey, certClient);` - This works on Android version less than 12 but on Android 12 it's giving below error:

`RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:VALUE_MISSING`

I also tried to target Android 12 to use `WifiNetworkSpecifier` but didn't find any option to pass X509 with this API. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Android12, there are something specific. Please check the link below. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware#initial_setup

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thanks for your reply. I went through that link but there's no mention of establishing a WiFi connection that requires X509 certificate as an authentication.